# Simplifying Rational Expression (Excluded Values)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would like some opinions on a problem that I am working. The problem is below.

Simplify the expression.

$$\frac{3n+6}{n+6}\cdot \frac{2n-10}{3n+6}$$
So, I simplified and got
$$\frac{2n-10}{n+6}$$

I understand why the two expressions above are not equal when n = -2. I would like to know if the two expressions are equal when n = -6. Is $$\frac{264}{0}=\frac{-22}{0}$$ a true statement? I know that the two fractions written above are undefined. Is it okay to say the the two rational expressions above that are equivalent when n = -6 since they both produce similar results (undefined = undefined)?

Comment: They are both undefined, it is meaningless to say anything about equality or inequality.

Comment: Where'd you get $2n + 10$ from?

Comment: How come you have $2n -10$ in the first part then?

Comment: It is correct now.

Comment: I'd argue the simplification needs to be $\frac {2n-10}{n+6}; n\ne -2$.  I'd say you *must* indicate that $n$ is not allowed to be $-2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unless you define what you mean by 'equivalent'. Division by $0$ traditionally has no meaning, so I guess they could be 'equivalent' in their 'meaninglessness'.

Notice that regardless of how you define 'equivalent', do not mistake 'equivalent' for 'equal'. The equality symbol has well defined meaning and properties, and division by $0$ does not interact properly with it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference between 'equivalent' and 'equal'.

Answer (score 0):

You don't talk of two expressions being equal, by talking about if they are equal  at the points they are both undefined.  You talk of two expressions being equal if the are equal at all the points where they *are* defined *and if they are both defined and/or undefined at the same points*.

$\frac{3n+6}{n+6}\cdot \frac{2n-10}{3n+6}$ and $\frac{2n-10}{n+6}$ are *not* both equal at $n= -6$.  They are both *undefined* at $n=-6$.

To be equal they must i) both be equal at all points they are both defined.  And if $n \ne -6$ and $n\ne -2$ they *are* equal.  ii) be (un)defined at the same points.  And they are both undefined at $n= -6$ and they are both defined for all $n\ne -6; n\ne -2$. *BUT* $\frac{2n-10}{n+6}$ is defined at $n=-2$ (it is equal to $-\frac 72$) whereas $\frac{3n+6}{n+6}\cdot \frac{2n-10}{3n+6}$ is *not* definied at $n=-2$.  So the expressions are not equal.

....

Perhaps a clear example of what you are trying to express.

$\frac {x+1}{x^2 + 2x + 1} = \frac 1{x+1}$.

These expression are equal because if $x \ne -1$ then we have the terms are equal.

But  if $x$ *does* equal $-1$ we *don't* have the two expressions equal.  And saying $\frac 00 = \frac 10$ is *FALSE*.

They are *not* equal at $x=-1$.

But they are both *undefined* at $x= -1$.  And so, at all points we have either the two expressions both equal or they are both undefined.  So they are equal.

....

Anyway.... we don't have $\frac{3n+6}{n+6}\cdot \frac{2n-10}{3n+6}=\frac{2n-10}{n+6}$ but we *do* have $\frac{3n+6}{n+6}\cdot \frac{2n-10}{3n+6}=\frac{2n-10}{n+6}_{n\ne -2}$ where that notation, $_{n\ne -2}$ means we are restricting $\frac {2n-10}{n+6}$ only to values where $n\ne -1$.

These expressions *are* equal as they are both undefined and $n=-6$ and at $n=-2$ (the second is *not* defined ant $n=-2$ because we *said* it wasn't) and they are equal everywhere else.

....

P.S.  You wrote $2n+10$ rather than $2n-10$.  I'm assuming that was a typo.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. This sheds more light and brings clarity.
I believe you meant $n\neq -2$ at the end of the sentence that starts "Anyway...".
Yes, I mistyped $2n+10$ and meant $2n-10$ when I first posted the problem; it is correct now though.